# Set up Cron Job to excecute php script for javascript alert

Tags: javascript, php, cron

I am trying to set up a reminder system so that if the user selects a specific time for a task it will be stored in the database, then I want to set up a cron job to run every minute to check if anything exists for that time/user, and if show display a popup alert box on the active window. To start, I have just set up a php script which will always be true if the user is logged in, so that I can see if the cron job is working. It is not. And I do not know why. The php script works when I load the page but it is not being executed every minute.

alert.php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Your User ID is ".$_SESSION['username'].".');     </script>"; 
 ;
}

?>
```

html including alert.php on page:

```
<body>
<?php
require 'alert.php';
?>
```

cron job:

```
*   *   *   *   *   /home/myusername/public_html/alert.php >/dev/null
```

Comment: Would probably be easier to run this check from the client side with javascript and ajax. Then you're outsourcing the work to the client (bar the models/queries) and it is only being processed for those actually viewing the site at that time

Comment: The cron job is a separate process, it is not associated to any one user, and does not have a session id. Even if you pass it a session id, any output from the cron job will not been seen by any user

Comment: @Doctus is there a way to do that every minute like a cron job? The alert will need to happen at the specific time that the reminder is set for.

Comment: You can set javascript interval, and run an ajax call every minute..

Comment: I didn't even know that was possible. Thanks guys!

Comment: @PaigeRoseFigueira what Naruto said basically! If you are uncomfortable using javascript for ajax, then use jquery because it's a lot easier to get to grips with